# Java 3.6 Checking inputs

Tags: java, integer, do-while

Ask the user to "Input a number: " 4 times.
If the input is not a number, ask again.
Output "success." after they have entered 4 numbers.
Please answer this code for me using while, if, if else and do statements.

```
int counter; System.out.print("Input a number: "); 
while(!(scan.hasNextInt()));{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ 
    scan.next(); 
    System.out.print("Input a number: "); 
    if (!(pass.equals(pass2))) { 
      counter++; 
    } else if (!(scan.hasNextInt())) {

    }
  } 
  if (counter >= 2) { 
    System.out.println("Input a number: "); 
  }
} else if (!(scan.hasNextInt())) { System.out.println("success."); }
```

This is very basic stuff but I am struggling.

Comment: Is this a Java question or a JavaScript question? Java and JavaScript are completely different languages. Also, we expect that you will make an attempt and post that attempt here and not just post your requirement.

Comment: Show some of your code. We cannot help you if you don't have minimal code of your own.

Comment: int counter;
    System.out.print("Input a number: ");
  while(!(scan.hasNextInt()));{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      scan.next();
      System.out.print("Input a number: ");
    
  if (!(pass.equals(pass2))) {
        counter++;
        }

        else if (!(scan.hasNextInt())) {
        }
      }
      if (counter >= 2) {
        System.out.println("Input a number: ");
      }
    }

    else if (!(scan.hasNextInt())) {
      System.out.println("success.");
    }

Comment: This is a javascript question I believe I use repel it

Comment: The code you've shown is Java. Before you tackle it, it's imperative you know what language you are working in.

Comment: I am sorry I am not really good at coding

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] inputIntegers = new int[4]; // Array to save input
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
int counter = 0;
while(counter < 4) {
    System.out.println("Input a number: ");
    String input = scan.next();
    if(input.matches("[-]?[0-9]*")){  // Checking, if input is an integer
        inputIntegers[counter]=Integer.parseInt(input); // Persing string to integer
        counter++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Input is not an integer");
    }
}
System.out.println("Success");
scan.close(); //Do not forget do close scanner
```